# I'm encountering an error while enabling gunicorn.socket after running the command ---> sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket

Tags: deployment

after the statring the gunicorn `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket` then executing the next command I encourtered an error related to symlinks means they are not created after executing the sudo
systemctl enable gunicorn.socket..

```
manii@ubuntu0:~/projectdjango$ sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
manii@ubuntu0:~/projectdjango$ sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

showing this...

to configure the gunicorn to serve mysite...as it will be happen then I will configure nginx as reverse proxy.Then my site will be served with contingency whether server gets restared or resulted in powercut, site will be up and running within next few seconds